# Discord.net SlashCommand error - Invalid context type

Tags: discord, discord.net

I am writing my first Discord bot heavily based on the example code published at https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/tree/dev/samples/InteractionFramework

I am attempting to add a SlashCommand as per

```cs
        [SlashCommand("kavs", "This is a test.")]
        public async Task GreetUserAsync()
        {
            await RespondAsync(text: $"the command has worked", ephemeral: true);
        }
```

When the bot is running, the SlashCommand looks to have been registered as when I type a "/" I see the following[image]

If I enter "/kavs" then I get the following error from the bot

[image]

On discord I see

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure the context you are creating matches the context the module expects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's beacause the `InteractionModuleBase` class has an overload which requires a generic type.

I fixed the issue by replacing the module base class

```
: InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext<SocketSlashCommand>>
```

with

```
: InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
```

Comment: Perfect ! It's working now :-)